# How can I compile the inner component as a child in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I know that normally all components are compiled globally and as siblings to each other. But I'm wondering how can I use the property of parent component? For example:

```js
Vue.component('parent',{
  template: '#parent',
  props:['tab']
});

Vue.component('child',{
  template: '#child',
  props:['scope']
});

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: function(){
   return {
     tab: "global"
   }
  }
});
```

```html
<parent tab="parent">
  <child slot="child" :scope="tab"></child>
</parent>

<template id="parent">
  <h1>Parent</h1>
  <slot name="child"></slot>
</template>
<template id="child">
  <p>Compiled in {{scope}}</p>
</template>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case i'd use local registration for the child component. Instead of making it global you can register it locally like:

```
// extend and register in one step
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
})

// also works for local registration
var Parent = Vue.extend({
  components: {
    'my-component': {
      template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
    }
  }
})
```

> You don’t have to register every component globally. You can make a component available only in the scope of another component by registering it with the components instance option:

http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Local-Registration

Comment: `Vue.component` registers it globally, you should point that out.

Comment: He mentions that in his original question @gurghet

Comment: Can you please take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsbin.com/lefofudimo/edit?html,js,output)? I just register the component locally but still get a warning says `Unknown custom element`

Comment: @KarlBao this is the correct way: https://jsbin.com/tomabakudo/1/edit?html,js,output. When you register it as a component on the parent you can only use it in the parent. That's the only way to get the parent / child communication. 

If you want to use it like you are doing in your fiddle you'll need to register it on the global like you were before but you lose any communication. You would have to use a state store like Vuex.